# Options to make it a drop down & removal of top 'start' & 'continous' date?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-date-range

Attached here is the image of react-date-range npm package.

I need the following.

1. I want this to be a dropdown, so it won't permanently occupy space. I don't see any options on doing this anywhere.
2. I want to remove the below Aug 27, 2020 and Sep 3, 2020 to boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- For your Second Point -  If you want to hide the default text boxes
  showing dates, you can add this to your CSS

  ```
   .rdrDateDisplayWrapper {
     display: none; 
   }
  ```
- For your First Point if you want your date picker calendar to be
  visible as per your need, you can make two custom text fields for both dates and render this date-range-picker when the user clicks on any of these fields.

**You can check this link for the working and customized example here - [Customize Date Range Picker As Per Your Need](https://www.snagoff.com/blog/date-range-picker-example-using-react-date-range-customized/)**